# Package 'gcc' has no installation update

Tags: gcc

After using `sudo apt-get install gcc`, package 'gcc' has no installation update issue is being shown. How to solve this error?

Comment: Did you mean to write *"has no installation **candidate**"*?

Answer (score 0):

May be you have latest version, at least in your repositories.

That's mine output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc
[sudo] password for leonid: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1).
gcc set to manually installed.
```